# How to refer to the n attribute in the lg element of TEI xml document in XSLT to create a LaTeX output (for using reledmac to make PDF)

Tags: xml, xslt, latex

I want to ultimately print the verse number, e.g. §1, encoded in the XML as `<lg n="1">` , in my pdf output. Here's an example of my XML document:

```
        <teiHeader>
            ...
        </teiHeader>
        <text>
            ...
            <body>
                <head>
                    ...
                </head>
                <div>
                    <lg n="1">
                        <l n="1">
                           verse one line one of the poem</l>
                        <l n="2">
                            verse one line two</l>
                        <l n="3">...ditto </l>
                        <l n="4">...ditto </l>
                    </lg>
                    <lg n="2">
                        <l n="1">...
                    </lg>
...
```

I am preparing a critical edition of a poem of this structure, and since I am a novice to XML, TEI, XSLT, and LaTeX, I cannot figure out how to reference the n="1" part in the xslt so that LaTeX prints it. I am trying to use the stylesheet posted on [TEI Critical Apparatus Toolbox](http://teicat.huma-num.fr/print.php) that transforms XML into LaTeX with the reledmac package (the link to the XSLT file is under "Advanced Customisation"). The relevant part seems to be these lines, though I don't understand how this works. I just want to tweak it so that my verse numbers, and perhaps even my line numbers, can be referenced and printed:

```
<!-- inserts linegroup into document-->
  <xsl:template match="tei:lg">

    <!-- lg is a pain because it can occur in p (or not), but in tex it generates a stanza structure which must never be inside a paragraph
    I've tried closing the parent paragraph and re-opening one, but it's not enough. 
    If the lg are inside a quotation, for instance, we need to have some more complicated handling.
    -->

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(ancestor::tei:rdg)">
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::tei:p and not(preceding-sibling::tei:lg)">
          <!-- In TEI an lg can occur within a p, while in LaTeX a stanza cannot occur within a pstart. The only solution I came up with was to close then re-open the current paragraph. 
        Warning: this can create a problem in the .tex file when the lg occurs at the very beginning or end of the paragraph. -->
          <xsl:text>
                \pend </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>                     
        \stanza[ ] </xsl:text>

        <!-- this is not good; TODO: do better. -->
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::tei:cit">
          <xsl:if
            test="ancestor::tei:quote[position() = 1]/descendant::node()[name() = 'lg'][position() = 1] = self::node()">
            <xsl:text>\edlabel{cit_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:number select="ancestor::tei:quote[position() = 1]" level="any"/>
            <xsl:text>_start}</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your template matching a `tei:lg` element you can select `@n` in XPath to select the attribute named `n` and in XSLT output e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="@n"/>` to output the attribute's value (e.g. `1`).

Comment: Thanks so much! I cannot believe how simple the change was! I placed the line "<xsl:value-of select="@n"/> " right after  "<xsl:template match="tei:lg">," before everything else, and it worked like a charm!